# Converting image url in C# into vb.net equivalent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, base64, c#-to-vb.net

Please i need help in converting the image url property of an image control written in C# to its equivalent in vb.net. I am following a tutorial which i got from this site on how to display images on a gridview using base64 this is the url of the tutorial. http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-insert-image-into-database-and.html. The tutorial was written in C# please i need the equivalent of this in vb.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Picture").ToString() == ""?"": GetImageString64((byte[])Eval("Picture")) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%# If(Eval("Picture").ToString() = "", "", GetImageString64(CType(Eval("Picture"), Byte()))) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here's how it works:

```
If( argument1, argument2, argument3 )
```

the above syntax will evaluate `argument1`. If `argument1` is true, it will return `argument2`, otherwise it will return `argument3`.

In your case `argument1` is `Eval("Picture").ToString() = ""`, `argument2` is `""`, and `argument3` is `GetImageString64(CType(Eval("Picture"), Byte()))`.